# Selenium invoke multiple sessions chrome driver

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

- OS: Windows 7
- Chrome Driver Version: Same behaviour with 2.24 & 2.26
- JDK: 1.8
- selenium-java: 3.0.1

When I am trying to run two different tests with chrome driver each in different JVM, First one runs ok but the second one is failing.

Observation: 
For the second run, Chrome session is opened as a tab in the first session. The first time I try to intract with the session its failing with below error. But I could see that session is there as a tab.

Possible Solution:
Ensure that second session is opened as a separate session and not as a tab in the first session. Please suggest on how to solve this issue.

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: no such session
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.24.417431 (9aea000394714d2fbb20850021f6204f2256b9cf),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 16 milliseconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'BGC-BE-CB6E0D7B', ip: '10.115.14.44', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_112'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{message=unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.24.417431 (9aea000394714d2fbb20850021f6204f2256b9cf),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64), platform=ANY}]
Session ID: 466aa659b01ebf31f161293c86f2da8d
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructo
```

Comment: please share the code of two tests. also, tell us how are you running the tests?

Comment: Have you tried updating your chrome driver?

Comment: Could not try more recent then 2.26. I have restrictions on versions that I can use as they are not available my corporate software center yet. I will see if I can try more recent versions.

Comment: Naveen, In my post I described about the issue that I faced when I run two jobs at the same time in Jenkins. Same issue was noticed when I have a open chrome session before starting a test. In test when I create web driver instance new chrome instance is getting launched as a tab in already opened chrome session. And the first request to web driver is failing with NoSuchSessionException exception. Using local driver(No Grid or Remote Driver).